# how to wait for batch command to complete its excecution in java

Tags: java, process, batch-processing, runtime.exec

I want to wait till my batch command completes its execution and creates a CSV file as output. The code is as bellow for executing batch file

```
String command = "cmd /c start " + batFile;
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process pr = rt.exec(command);
```

Then I want to use the CSV file(app.csv) to read the contents of it. But when I run the program, I am getting like.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\appanalysis\app.csv (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:41)
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199119/runtime-exec-waitfor-doesnt-wait-until-process-is-done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [pr.waitFor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29) this method will return the exit code, anything other than 0 the process failed.

Insted of `String command = "cmd /c start " + batFile;` use `String command = "cmd /c " + batFile`

Comment: ya i used it but getting same file not found for my first run

Comment: Is the batch file creating the CSV file?

Comment: ya it is creating csv file to my local directory ....so my program statements immediate after Process pr = rt.exec(command);  int exitVal = pr.waitFor(); is to use the CSV file for analysis. But getting file not found

Comment: Insted of String command = "cmd /c start " + batFile; try String command = "cmd /c " + batFile;

Answer (score 0):

`Runtime.exec` returns a `Process` object (`pr`, in your example above). Just call `pr.waitFor()` to wait for the process to exit.