# wait the end of the execution of a process

Tags: java, xml

In my code I'm trying to convert a file MDL to file XML using simex as a tool.
Then I will use this xml file for some analysis.
When I convert this file manually or if i treat a small model (via Process....)
,no error has been occured.

The problem is when I try to convert a big model via Process using this code :

```
if(!(xmlFile.exists()))
{Process child;

    child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C start /min "+System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\simex\\MDLtoXML.bat "+path+" "+xmlpath+" " +System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\simex\\",null,null);
     try {
        child.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This code work good with a small model ,so I think the problem that's my project analyse the xml file before the end of transformation because the error is
:
**Exception in thread "main" org.jdom2.input.JDOMParseExeception:Error on line of document file (......XML):Fin  prématurée du fichier............**

So I want to know how can wait the end of the transformation then execute the second part of the analyse of xml File.

**Nb:**
I have also tried to put

```
child.getInputStream().close();
child.getOutputStream().close();
```

before **child.waitFor();**

Somaya.

Comment: Well, if you are getting an exception, hasn't the child process stopped running anyways?

Comment: The child process stop after the generation of the exeception .

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the same issue as discussed here:
[Runtime.exec().waitFor() doesn't wait until process is done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199119/runtime-exec-waitfor-doesnt-wait-until-process-is-done)

Remove the `start` parameter to run the shell in foreground not in background mode, so that Java waits for it.